# Wallet problem solution?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, paradoxes

There is a problem proposed by Maurice Kraitchik that is supposedly unsolved(according to [this VSauce2 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTDhz3x92zw)):

Take two people and compare the amount of money that is in their wallets. The person who has less gets all of it. If X is person 1's money and Y is person 2's, person 1 has a possible gain of X + Y and possible Loss of -X, making the average gain Y.

But these two values are not the same, aren't they? The first one(X + Y) is the money Person 1 ends up with, while the second one(-X) is their loss. When you just compare the gains/losses(aka relative to X) the paradox goes away:

Person 1's gain: Y; Person 1's loss: -X

Where did I go wrong(or am I right)?

Comment: How can person one gain $X+Y$? If he wins, he ends up with $X+Y$ which is a gain of $Y$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnDouma Exactly what I was thinking(and what I was trying to say).

Comment: The average gain is not going to be just the sum of the win and the loss,  because they aren't equally  likely, depending on how $X$ and $Y$ are distributed

Comment: @Alan That averages out when considering Player 2's outcomes. Among the two, the average gain, according to the paradox, is $(X + Y) / 2$

Comment: Please don't require your readers on MSE to watch videos to understand your questions unless you are unable to summarise the information in the video in mathematics. As @Alan has pointed out, the information you provide above is insufficient to answer the question. There must be something quite odd about the distributions if the expected gain in what appears to be a completely symmetric game is non-zero.

Comment: @RobArthan I believe I summed everything the video said up in the second paragraph.

Comment: Well if that is all the video said, it is insufficient to provide any meaningful answer to the question.